# login to magento 2 admin using API token

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I have a react dashboard that gets data from Magento 2 via Rest API using token based authentication.
I want a button somewhere in my reach dashboard to auto-login to Magento 2 admin backend.

How to achieve this?